# JOptionPane with custom array JButtons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, button, dialog

I have this code but it doesnt work with the array of buttons

```
        JButton[] option = new JButton[2];
        option[0].setText("sad");
        option[0].setEnabled(true);
        option[1].setText("sasdd");
        option[1].setEnabled(true);
        Object[] options = {option[0], option[1]};
        int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "SADASD", "dfgdfgg", 0, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

If I make single button works perfect but I need to be on an array for controling some of them.

Comment: you just declared an array of JButtons, but never instantiated any of them. you just need to say option[0] = new JButton(); option[1] = new JButton(); before accessing option[0], option[1]. And you should do this in a for loop or something...

Comment: ohhh yes.... my bad... i forgot it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting values you have to create JButton objects like this:

```
option[0] = new JButton();
option[1] = new JButton();
```

Write this lines just after creating the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] options = {"Java", "C", "C++", "C#"};
String msg = "What is your favourite language";
String title = "Language Poll";
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parentComponent, msg, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
if(result == options[0] {
    //do some thing
} else {
.......
}
```

....